# css selectors query

Tags: html, css

Here is a little piece of code.

```
<style ...>
h1 { color: red }
h2 { color: olive }
em { color: red }
h1 em { color: blue }
</style ...>

<body>
<H1>This <h2>headline is <EM>very</EM> important</h2> to me.</H1>
</body>
```

I even tried this code at jsfiddle, but couldn't understand WHY that last two words **to me** appear in black color. I thought it would be red.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because you cannot nest h1-h6 tags. The `<h2>` tag implicitly closes `<h1>` so it is interpreted as:

```
<body>
<H1>This </H1><h2>headline is <EM>very</EM> important</h2> to me.
</body>
```

Comment: Psht, I didn't catch that. I would, however, suggest lowercasing the `<em>` tags.

Comment: ok agree. Why then the word VERY is in red, why not blue. em tag in any way descendant of h1 tag.

Comment: Just to add that the browser automatically close he `h1`. So when it finds the text node "to me" its parent is the same as the parent of `h1`.

Comment: @Dbz: I also prefer lowercase tags but since they are [case-insensitive in HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/documents.html#case-insensitivity) it doesn't really matter, they can be even `<eM>` tags, just a matter of taste.

Comment: @rsp, I think it matters a little bit. First off, the code won't validate for xhtml. Second off, XML is case-sensitive, so `<em>` and `<EM>` are treated as two different things. Nevertheless, most likely it won't matter- it's good practice though

Comment: @Rahul Utb: "very" is in red because `em { color: red }` is more specific to this EM tag than `h2 { color: olive }`. This `h1 em { color: blue }` doesn't apply to anything because there is no EM in H1 in what the browser sees.

Comment: @Dbz: You're right, this is not valid XHTML. I just assumed it's plain HTML 4 or HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Note that styles have to go in the `<head>` section.

But you could try putting it in a style sheet?

Also what is the `...` in the `<style>` tags?